# Introducing Data in a postgresql database with HTML / PHP - Ubuntu

Tags: php, html, postgresql, ubuntu

Working in Ubuntu with postgresql.

I'm trying to insert data in my postgresql database through a form in HTML with php.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<html>
<body>
    <form action="add.php" method="post">
        First Name : <input type="text" name="firstname" size="40" length="40" value="First Name"><BR>
        Surname : <input type="text" name="surname" size="40" length="40" value="Surname"><BR>
        Email Address : <input type="text" name="emailaddress" size="40" length="40" value="Email Address"><BR>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
        <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Clear It">
    </form>
</body>
</html>

<form action="add.php" method="post">
```

Here my PHP file:

```
<html>
<body>
    <?php
    $db = pg_connect('host=localhost dbname=postgres user=myusername password=mypassword');

    $firstname = pg_escape_string($_POST['firstname']);
    $surname = pg_escape_string($_POST['surname']);
    $emailaddress = pg_escape_string($_POST['emailaddress']);

    $query = "INSERT INTO friends(firstname, surname, emailaddress) VALUES('" . $firstname . "', '" . $surname . "', '" . $emailaddress . "')";
    $result = pg_query($query);
    if (!$result) {
        $errormessage = pg_last_error();
        echo "Error with query: " . $errormessage;
        exit();
    }
    printf ("These values were inserted into the database - %s %s %s", $firstname, $surname, $emailaddress);
    pg_close();
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

I sit those files in the folder, \var\www\html\
Apache is running and I have my database set up to be used.

When I open the .html file introduce some data and click in "Submit" its open the php file in the editor instead of sending the data to the database. I check the database and it is empty, nothing has been introduced.

This is a printshoot of what happens when pressing "Submit"

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Here is the screenshoot from the localhost (Seams that Apache running and working)

[image]

Here the screenshoot of the ports.conf file

[image]

And Below the apache2.conf file. Please let me know if there is further info need it. I'm new on this. I really appreciate your help

```
# Summary of how the Apache 2 configuration works in Debian:
# The Apache 2 web server configuration in Debian is quite different to
# upstream's suggested way to configure the web server. This is because     Debian's
# default Apache2 installation attempts to make adding and removing         modules,
# virtual hosts, and extra configuration directives as flexible as        possible, in
# order to make automating the changes and administering the server as easy as
# possible.

# It is split into several files forming the configuration hierarchy outlined
# below, all located in the /etc/apache2/ directory:
#
#   /etc/apache2/
#   |-- apache2.conf
#   |   `--  ports.conf
#   |-- mods-enabled
#   |   |-- *.load
#   |   `-- *.conf
#   |-- conf-enabled
#   |   `-- *.conf
#   `-- sites-enabled
#       `-- *.conf
#
#
# * apache2.conf is the main configuration file (this file). It puts the pieces
#   together by including all remaining configuration files when starting up the
#   web server.

# * ports.conf is always included from the main configuration file. It is
#   supposed to determine listening ports for incoming connections which can be
#   customized anytime.

# * Configuration files in the mods-enabled/, conf-enabled/ and sites-enabled/
#   directories contain particular configuration snippets which manage modules,
#   global configuration fragments, or virtual host configurations,
#   respectively.

#   They are activated by symlinking available configuration files from their
#   respective *-available/ counterparts. These should be managed by using our
#   helpers a2enmod/a2dismod, a2ensite/a2dissite and a2enconf/a2disconf. See
#   their respective man pages for detailed information.

# * The binary is called apache2. Due to the use of environment variables, in
#   the default configuration, apache2 needs to be started/stopped with
#   /etc/init.d/apache2 or apache2ctl. Calling /usr/bin/apache2 directly will not
#   work with the default configuration.


# Global configuration



# ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's
# configuration, error, and log files are kept.

# NOTE!  If you intend to place this on an NFS (or otherwise network)
# mounted filesystem then please read the Mutex documentation (available
# at <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#mutex>);
# you will save yourself a lot of trouble.

# Do NOT add a slash at the end of the directory path.

#ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"


# The accept serialization lock file MUST BE STORED ON A LOCAL DISK.

Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default


# PidFile: The file in which the server should record its process
# identification number when it starts.
# This needs to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars

PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}


# Timeout: The number of seconds before receives and sends time out.

Timeout 300


# KeepAlive: Whether or not to allow persistent connections (more than
# one request per connection). Set to "Off" to deactivate.

KeepAlive On


# MaxKeepAliveRequests: The maximum number of requests to allow
# during a persistent connection. Set to 0 to allow an unlimited amount.
# We recommend you leave this number high, for maximum performance.

MaxKeepAliveRequests 100


# KeepAliveTimeout: Number of seconds to wait for the next request from the
# same client on the same connection.

KeepAliveTimeout 5


# These need to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}


# HostnameLookups: Log the names of clients or just their IP addresses
# e.g., www.apache.org (on) or 204.62.129.132 (off).
# The default is off because it'd be overall better for the net if people
# had to knowingly turn this feature on, since enabling it means that
# each client request will result in AT LEAST one lookup request to the
# nameserver.

HostnameLookups Off

# ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
# If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
# container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
# logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
# container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log


# LogLevel: Control the severity of messages logged to the error_log.
# Available values: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
# error, crit, alert, emerg.
# It is also possible to configure the log level for particular modules, e.g.
# "LogLevel info ssl:warn"

LogLevel warn

# Include module configuration:
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

# Include list of ports to listen on
Include ports.conf


# Sets the default security model of the Apache2 HTTPD server. It does
# not allow access to the root filesystem outside of /usr/share and /var/www.
# The former is used by web applications packaged in Debian,
# the latter may be used for local directories served by the web server.  If
# your system is serving content from a sub-directory in /srv you must allow
# access here, or in any related virtual host.
<Directory />
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
AllowOverride None
Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Require all granted
</Directory>

#<Directory /srv/>
#   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
#   AllowOverride None
#   Require all granted
#</Directory>


# AccessFileName: The name of the file to look for in each directory
# for additional configuration directives.  See also the AllowOverride
# directive.

AccessFileName .htaccess


# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being
# viewed by Web clients.

<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
Require all denied
</FilesMatch>


# The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
# a customLog directive.

# These deviate from the Common Log Format definitions in that they use %O
# (the actual bytes sent including headers) instead of %b (the size of the
# requested file), because the latter makes it impossible to detect partial
# requests.

# Note that the use of %{X-Forwarded-For}i instead of %h is not recommended.
# Use mod_remoteip instead.

LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

# Include of directories ignores editors' and dpkg's backup files,
# see README.Debian for details.

# Include generic snippets of statements
IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

# Include the virtual host configurations:
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Thank you very much

Comment: That's a web server configuration problem, it does not know what to do with a PHP file. Try to use PHP’s stand alone server (`php -S`)

Comment: Could you please be more specific? I'm a little lost. I typed in php - S in the terminal and it provide me with a bunch of commands but I'm not really sure what are you suggesting me to do. Thank you much

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter in the `pg_query` function should be the connection, then the query string.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query.php

So: `$result = pg_query($db,$query);`

---

UPDATE:

Based on the new screenshot, your PHP script is not being executed because you have an issue with how it is configured. You need to post more information of your web server configuration (Apache, Nginx, etc).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I made the change bud I still having the same issue.

Comment: Please find the update in the original post with the configuration files for Apache. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

ok, I make it work.

It was just that I was running var/www/html/file.html and I had to run

localhost/file.html

Thanks